# save image to a record : ServiceNow

Tags: javascript, html, servicenow

I have a journal field on my form. I am copy pasting images from a webpage to this journal field. Unfortunately these images are saved as references to that webpage. Is there a way that I can save these images to that form(or record)?

Answer (score 0):

Need more info to help you. What version are you running?

Assuming Geneva or later, adding an image attachment to a record automatically makes it show up in the activity log. You cannot place an image in a journal field directly.

Comment: Hello, I am using Geneva. We are using slack for conversations. When I copy-paste my slack chat in html field, images and text is properly organised to html field which works fine for me but slack chat expires every 60-90days so I will eventually loose those images that are pasted in HTML field because those images are just reference to slack url. they are not saved to the ticket. that is why i am looking for some mechanism, that when i copy paste my slack chat to servicenow it should save to a record permanently, independent of where I copied it from.